# How to mention my freelancing projects of a suspended profile?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search, freelancing

I have been working on Upwork as a Software Engineer for 3 years and had a very successful career until my profile got suspended few days ago.

I worked in a company for 1 year but after that i just did fulltime freelancing.

I had mentioned the projects which i did on Upwork, on my resume and all other job related sites like indeed.com
I had also mentioned link to my Upwork profile as well.

But as i said that my profile is suspended permanently, i am not able to work, not even my work history is visible, they completely deleted my profile.

So how do i mention my projects in my resume? How do i tell in interviews that i worked on Upwork, obviously telling them i got suspended is not good idea.

**P.S:**
The projects i did have no online link to see them in action, those are Data Mining projects which help clients to scrape data from different sources.

Comment: Is there some way you can ask why your profile got suspended? Seems rather strange to me they'd delete all traces of your successful career without any appeal.

Comment: They dont tell you clear reasons why they suspended. They said i violated their Terms and Policies... But why would i do that to get suspended... You can google Account suspended permanently upwork... And you will find that Upwork sucks... Their customer support is almost a Bot system with templated replies...

Answer (score 3):

My answer is possibly oversimplistic, but it can actually be done:

Include descriptions of your work and your jobs without including links to them.

Resumes and job applications predate the internet by a long, long time.  A website URL for more information (or even just proof) of the particular jobs you describe in your resume is nice to include, but since you can't include it you will have to do without.  Pretend it is the 19th century and write out your employment history and the work you did with proper descriptions that stand by themselves without raising more questions than they answer.

Comment: Most professional software development cannot be linked to a prospective employer. I certainly couldn't share my company's proprietary code. It would have been great to link your Upwork account, but that doesn't preclude you from discussing what you'd done.